# How can I read a text file to dataframe in Pandas with columns with different lenght and missing data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file like this:

[image]

As you can notice some values are missing data and the file contains some fields with a string with spaces.

I need an output like the following:

[image]

[image]

When missing data just leave the field blank. Also do not put a comma between the words "No" and "Presento". Is there a way to delimit and separate with comma each field according to a certain length? Here each field has a certain length but I don't know how to convert it to a dataframe.

I remember do something like this in bash with the function `substr()`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by a classic [**`pandas.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) :

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'path_to_your_textfile.txt', sep='\t', header=None)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

       0      1            2    3     4   5            6    7
0  Test1   90.0  No presento   67  99.0  67     Aprobado   89
1  Test2  100.0           96   76   NaN  76  No aprobado  100
2  Test3    NaN  No presento   89  80.0  99     Aprobado   78
3  Test4   78.0          100  100  83.0  88          NaN   96
```

If needed, you can save the dataframe to a new text file with a `,` separator with [**`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df.to_csv(r'path_to_your_new_texfile.txt', header=None, index=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, @abokey, unfortunately they are not '\t' tabs but spaces. I don't have control over how the file is generated. But i can see with the command `od -xc [file]` spaces, not tabs. The only way i guess can get a solution for this is extracting delimited substrings, but i don't know how. Each field has a specific length. Thanks for your help!